# How can I configure datasource in my spring project?

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, datasource, wildfly-10

I am using wildfly 10.1.0.
I would  like to config datasource in my project.
Though I read the wildfly document, I cannot find how to configure datasource in spring project.
Please help me.

Comment: Is your question, how do I configure Spring to lookup a container managed datasource, or is your question, how to configure a datasource in Wildfly?

Comment: Are you using spring boot? or just spring MVC? if spring mvc then xml config or java config?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure datasource properties in wildfly for all the projects that you want to deploy on wildfly you need to do this :

1. open up the configuration in wildfly management portal.
2. view system properties.
3. Add a key value properties of datasource like

   `key = datasource.username
   value = abcdef`
4. once added use the key defined in wildfly in your properties or yml file like
    spring.datasource.username=${datasource.username}